# I am working on an Android app and want to upload image to the server so can anyone give me the Java code in Android Studio to do so

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have an api endpoint stored in an String url = "API_endpoint". I want to upload an image through my app to that API endpoint using Volley or Retrofit library. I need to give the ("Authorisation",token) as header and the photo will be send in the form data ("file",image). Can anyone help me out to do so.

I am trying to upload an image to the server using my API endpoint but I tried almost everything but I was not able to do so.